# How to display the day with array_intersect

Tags: php, arrays

I have to set of arrays 1. is an array of working day while 2. is the day name. I want to display the name of the day from 1. But the array is different. I tried to use `array_intersect`. But it's not working.

**$weekDay**

```
$weekDay=array("1"=>"Mon","2"=>"Tue","3"=>"Wed","4"=>"Thu","5"=>"Fri","6"=>"Sat","7"=>"Sun");
```

**$opDay**

```
=0,0,0,4,0,0,7
```

So, I expect the result to show like this : `Thu,Sun`. So I write the function:

```
function opd($a1,$a2){
    $result=array_intersect($a1,$a2);
    return $result; 
}
```

But, because of the array is not intersectable. So the function is not working while I call:

```
opd($weekDay,$opDay);
```

Is there any function to do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The day IDs that you're using are the keys of `$weekDay` while they're the values of `$opDay`, so you need to flip one of the arrays to make an intersection:

```
function opd($a1, $a2)
{
    $return = array_intersect(array_flip($a1), $a2);
    return implode(',', array_keys($return));
}
```

[Example](https://eval.in/532312)